# how to create a pyramid using for loop in c++

Tags: c++

Hello guys I just want to ask how can I create a triangle using c++?

Actually I have my code but I don't have an idea how to center the first asterisk in the triangle. My triangle is left align. How can I make it a pyramid?

Here's my code below.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x,y;
    char star = '*';
    char space = ' p ';
    int temp;   

    for(x=1; x <= 23; x++){ 

        if((x%2) != 0){

            for(y=1; y <= x ; y++){     

                cout << star;
            }

            cout << endl;           
        }       
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is a triagke or link to a definition?

Comment: I think the goal is to make a pyramid with each row of asterisks being centered over the last row

Comment: @sinsedrix - look on your keyboard. 'ro' -> 'to' and 'triangke' -> 'triangle' (the correct keys are next to the used keys) Couldn't you work that out yourself, or were you just trying to be clever?

Comment: Yes that's what I want. Sorry for the wrong title

Comment: During the time describing your homework here, you should have reflected about the algorithm ... tip: if you start with `y = 0`, the distance between the `star` and the middle is `y` (position for your star is `y == std::abs(x - middle`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the number of spaces needed to center each row use this algorithm:

`numSpaces = (23 - x) / 2;`

and then a `for` loop to apply the spaces `numSpaces` times.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x,y;
    char star = '*';
    char space = ' p ';
    int temp;
    int numSpaces = 0;

    for(x=1; x <= 23; x++){ 

        if((x%2) != 0){
            numSpaces = (23 - x) / 2;  // Calculate number of spaces to add

            for(int i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) // Apply the spaces
            {
                cout << " ";
            }       

            for(y=1; y <= x ; y++){     

                cout << star;                   

            }   
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
           *
          ***
         *****
        *******
       *********
      ***********
     *************
    ***************
   *****************
  *******************
 *********************
***********************
```

Answer (score 3):

For a triangle och height Y, then first print Y-1 spaces, followed by an asterisk and a newline. Then for the next line print Y-2 spaces, followed by three asterisks (two more than previously printed) and a newline. For the third line print Y-3 spaces followed by five asterisks (again two more than previous line) and a newline. Continue until you have printed your whole triangle.

Something like the following

```
int asterisks = 1;
for (int y = HEIGHT; y > 0; --y, asterisks += 2)
{
    for (int s = y - 1; s >= 0; --s)
        std::cout << ' ';

    for (int a = 0; a < asterisks; ++a)
        std::cout << '*';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of it sir?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do
this is to nest two inner loops, one to print spaces and one to print *(s), inside an outer
loop that steps down the screen from line to line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int row = 5;
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(int j=row; j>i; j--){
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(int k=0; k<2*i+1; k++){
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is in C#, but you can convert it in c++.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int n = 5; // Number of lines to print.
            for(int i = 1; i<= n; i++){
                //loop for print space in the order (4,3,2,1,0) i.e n-i; 
                for(int j= 1; j<= n-i; j++){
                Console.Write(" ");    
                }
                //loop for print * in the order (1,3,5,7,9..) i.e 2i-1; 
                for(int k= 1; k<= 2*i-1; k++){
                Console.Write("*");    
                }
                Console.WriteLine(); // Next Line.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that doesn't use division or `if` statements

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main() {

    int height = 17, rowLength, i, j, k;
    char symbol = '^';

    // print a pyramid with a default height of 17
    rowLength = 1;
    for (i = height; i > 0; i--) {      // print a newline
        cout << endl;

        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)        // print leading spaces
            cout << " ";

        for (k = 0; k < rowLength; k++) // print the symbol
            cout << symbol;

        rowLength = rowLength + 2;      // for each row increase the number of symbols to print
    }
    cout << "\n\n ";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Star pyramid using for loop only:-**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "enter the number of rows of pyramid you want : ";
    cin >> n;
    "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j <= n - i; ++j) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
            cout << setw(3) << "*";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that using **two loops**

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows, star, spaces;
    int number_of_stars = 5;
    int number_of_rows = number_of_stars;
    string str1 = "*"; 

    for (rows=1; rows <= number_of_rows; rows++) {
            for (spaces=1; spaces <= number_of_stars; spaces++) {
                    if (spaces==number_of_stars)
                    {
                         cout<<str1;
                         str1+="**";
                    }
                    else
                        cout<<(" ");
            }
            cout<<("\n");
            number_of_stars = number_of_stars - 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the result is

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

[Url of code on Online compiler](http://cpp.sh/3qvmw)

and you can solve it using **only  one loop**, its simple and easy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int numberOfLines=4;
    string spaces=string( numberOfLines , ' ' );//this is 4 spaces 
    string stars="*";
    while(spaces!="") 
    {
        cout<<spaces<<stars<<endl;
        spaces = spaces.substr(0, spaces.size()-1);
        stars+="**";
    }
}
```

[Url of code on Online compiler](http://cpp.sh/3pnnl)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int for1(int &row);//function declaration  

int rows;//global variable
int main()
{
    cout<<"enter the total number of rows  : ";
    cin>>rows;
    for1(rows);//function calling
    cout<<"just apply a space at the end of the asteric  and volla ";

}

int for1(int &row)//function definition 
{
    for(int x=1;x<=row;x++)//for loop for the lines 
    {
        for(int y=row;y>=x;y--) //for loop for spaces (dynamic loop)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for(int k=1;k<=x*2-x;k++)//for loop for asteric
        {
            cout<<"* ";/*apply a space and you can turn a reverse right angle triangle into a pyramid */
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate *how* and *why* this solves the issue? Just tossing some code ain't good practice.

Comment: well the thing is just by applying a space at  the end of the asteric of 3rd for loop makes it a pyramid instead of a right angle triangle

Comment: i hope the edited version gives your answer @PaulKertscher