# Making Pyramid in C++ Using functions & loops in program

Tags: c++

When i separate the loops it makes sense, but when i combine it i can't seem to create the pyramid correctly. It's a logical error. I'm not sure if the loop within the other loop wasn't done properly. The height is the number of rows to be displayed in the pyramid.

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;

/********** DO NOT ALTER THIS CODE **********/  
void printStar(int numStars){  
    int i;  
    for (i=1; i<=numStars; i = i+1)  
        cout<<"*";  
}  

void printSpace(int numSpaces){  
    int i;  
    for (i=1; i<=numSpaces; i = i+1)  
        cout<<" ";  
}  


/********** WRITE YOU CODE IN THE main **********/  
int main(){  

    int count, heigh,p;  
    cout<<"Please enter height"<<endl;  
    cin>>heigh;  

    for(count= heigh; count>=0; count= count-1) {  

        printSpace(count);  
        for(p= 1; p<=(heigh*2); p=p+2) {  
            printStar(p);  
        }  
        cout<<endl;  
    }  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your program, *watching* values in variables.  Please edit your post with the text of your debugging session.  Debugging is often faster than posting correctly to StackOverflow and waiting for a response or waiting for somebody to debug your program for you.

Comment: Or you could do a basic sanity check in your head first. E.g. the inner loop will always print the same number of stars each row (probably not what you want). Can you see why?

Comment: @daniiahye Show how the pyramid should look for odd and even heights.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a pyramid using for loop in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760080/how-to-create-a-pyramid-using-for-loop-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

We beginners should help each other.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/********** DO NOT ALTER THIS CODE **********/  
void printStar(int numStars){  
    int i;  
    for (i=1; i<=numStars; i = i+1)  
        cout<<"*";  
}  

void printSpace(int numSpaces){  
    int i;  
    for (i=1; i<=numSpaces; i = i+1)  
        cout<<" ";  
}

/********** WRITE YOU CODE IN THE main **********/  
int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative height of the pyramid (0 - exit): ";

        int height;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> height ) or ( height <= 0 ) ) break;

        std::cout << '\n';

        for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
        {
            printSpace( height - i - 1 );
            printStar( 2 * i + 1 );
            std::cout << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output can look like

```
Enter a non-negative height of the pyramid (0 - exit): 10

         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************

Enter a non-negative height of the pyramid (0 - exit): 5

    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********

Enter a non-negative height of the pyramid (0 - exit): 0
```

Take into account that in your program this loop

```
for(count= heigh; count>=0; count= count-1) {
```

has `heigh + 1` iterations instead of `heigh` iterations. And this loop

```
for(p= 1; p<=(heigh*2); p=p+2) {  
    printStar(p);  
}
```

does not make sense inside the outer loop.